# Drivers causing Windows to shutdown slowly

Tags: drivers, performance, shutdown

My PC (Dell XPS 15z, 8gb RAM, Windows 7, I7) has been taking a long time shutting down recently. I haven't installed anything new. 
In Control Panel -> Performance Information and tools -> Advanced Tools, I can see two issues under the "Performance Issues" section. One of which is showing that two issues are causing a slow shutdown. The two issues are:

[image]

I have uninstalled the Vodafone software ( I use a Vodafone 3G wireless dongle which doesn't need the software installed on the pc in order to work ) which did not help, and also searched google in order to try and find an update with no luck.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

UPDATE -------------

When starting my pc up, and only letting it load as far as the log on window (not actually logging on), and shutting the machine down from there, I get the same problem (about a 4 minute shutdown).

Answer (score 0):

To uninstall drivers, you'll need to go into **Device Manager** and uninstall them from there.

Go to Control Panel / System / Device Manager. Then you can either disable such device driver or uninstall it.

Your instincts were not wrong in that in **most cases**, uninstalling the related software through **Programs and features** will uninstall the device driver as well.  Sadly, that is not always the case.  It's times like these that turn people sour when it comes to uninstall routines.

Comment: I have tried that, but can not find the drivers in the device manager?

Comment: Try `View`->`Show Hidden Devices` in Device Manager.